# Equivalence between the SDP and the given problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, semidefinite-programming

I read in a paper that the matrix minimization problem

$$
\mathbf{f(A)} = \min_{~~~~U,V\\\mathbf{A = UV'}} \max_i \mathbf{\|U_i\|} \max_i \mathbf{\|V_i\|} \\  \text{where } \mathbf{U_i} ~\text{and}~ \mathbf{V_i} ~ \text{are row vectors and } \|\cdot\| ~\text{is the}~ \ell_2 ~\text{norm}
$$

is equivalent to the below SDP

$$
\min ~\eta\\
X_{ii} \leq \eta \quad \forall i\\
X \succeq 0\\
X\circ B = F
$$

here

$$
B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & A\\\ A^T & 0\end{bmatrix} \; \text{and} \\
F = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \mathbf{1} \\ \mathbf{1} & 0\end{bmatrix}
$$  $\mathbf{1}$ is the matrix of all ones and $\circ$ is the Hadamard product.

I do not get it. How can I get the SDP from the original problem ?